# How can I pass a 2 decimal place float from flask-python to html?

Tags: python, flask, floating-point, decimal

Could you help me, please?

How can I pass a 2 decimal place float from flask-python to html?

I typed the following code in the application.py:

```
average = db.execute("SELECT AVG(score) FROM comments WHERE book_id = :book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).fetchall()
return render_template("comments.html", book=book, statements=statements, average=average)
```

And I typed in the html file:    .... jinjer

```
{{ average }}
```

I was expecting a value = 3, but the outcome was:

```
[(Decimal('3.0000000000000000'),)]
```

How can I fix it?

The value is ok, but the format is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the round function for precision in python. for example,

```
average = 2.34242433
average = round(average,2)
print(average)
```

**Output:** 2.34

So in your `application.py` file, return as

> `average=round(average,2)`

Comment: I input in the application.py: 
average = round(average, 2)

and input in the html file:
{{ average }}

But I got an error message:
average = round(average, 2)
TypeError: type RowProxy doesn't define _round_ method

I thought the round method was a Python buit-in function.

Do I need to import some library to define it such as: Matplotlib, Pandas or Numpy ?????

If I ignore the round() function it returns the right value but with an awful format with too many decimal places